# Right Click in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, right-click

I am a complete beginner to Python so dont understand the lingo. I want to use python to do a simple click at a specific point. I have already managed a left click using ctypes:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x,y), ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2,0,0,0,0), ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4,0,0,0,0)
```

is there a way to do a right click in the same way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the constants that you would use for `mouse_event`

```
MOUSE_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002     # left button down 
MOUSE_LEFTUP = 0x0004       # left button up 
MOUSE_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008    # right button down 
MOUSE_RIGHTUP = 0x0010      # right button up 
MOUSE_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020   # middle button down 
MOUSE_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040     # middle button up
```

In your code you are sending two events: `MOUSE_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSE_LEFTUP`. That simulates a "click".

Now for a right click you would send `MOUSE_RIGHTDOWN` and `MOUSE_RIGHTUP` in a similar fashion.

Comment: so for right down do i use (8,0,0,0,0) and (10,0,0,0,0) for right up?

Comment: `10` and `0x10` are two different things. First is in Base10, and represents decimal 10, and second is in hexadecimal, and represents 16. Except for this, yes, that would invoke a right-click

Comment: i just put in >>> import ctypes
>>> user32=ctypes.windll.user32
>>> user32.SetCursorPos(650,135), user32.mouse_event(8,0,0,0,0), user32.mouse_event(10,0,0,0,0)
and it didnt right click?

Comment: As I told you, it wont. Try `16` (or `0x10`) instead of `10`.

Comment: @Robert Thackeray: Did you see and understand the comment about hex vs decimal numbers?

Comment: @RobertThackeray Glad that helped. Please read up on the difference between Decimal and hex representation. That will help you in long run :)